# Developing a simple utility class( like a Date class )in java

Tags: java, date

I am a college student.

**In our college we have to develop a simple Date class in Java similar to the one available in java.util package.**

**If we do that then what are the methods we can implement in that class,
Since most of the methods are deprecated in original Date class.**

I saw the original Date class definitions in java/util/Date.java. Being a beginner to java, I could not understand the concepts of Serializable, Cloneable, Comparable ,and many variables like fasttime.

It will be good if we can implement this date class simply (since we have to develop this code as a test with in 3 hours at lab.)

Whether it is necessary to implement those concepts in a simple Date class.

If I take it as a Project and start developing the whole Date utilities, 
then that code will run to many pages
and I cannot finish it with 3 hours for our lab session.

So someone please guide me....

I have doubts about....

1. Whether it is possible to create a utility class similar to Date class with a simpler implementation.
2. If we do that, **then what are the methods we can implement in that class** , since most of the useful methods are deprecated in the original date class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you posting to SO for help *during* an examination?

Comment: I don't know why this is getting so many downvotes without an explanation, this is a valid question in my opinion.

Comment: I'm sure your lab TA can be of some help to you.

Comment: I don't think anybody can give an authoritative answer except for your professor.

Comment: @Michael Brewer-Davis no sir, but in our college they will provide only notepad and they will tell us to do within 3 hours for that only i need the program to be simpler and so that i can be understood by every student. otherwise i wont worry about program length and using difficult concepts

Comment: As the accepted answer suggests, `java.util.Date` is a bad role model for a date class, and in 2023 even more than in 2011. First, `java.util.Date` despite its name never represented a date. It represented a point in time (and a point in time that fell on at least two different dates in the time zones of the world). Second, it was always poorly designed, which was the reason for most of the constructors and methods to be deprecated in Java 1.1. -

Comment: - Third, `java.util.Date` is long outdated (no pun intended). It was replaced by [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) in Java 8 early in 2014. You may take inspiration from its `LocalDate` class, but please don’t feel obliged to do all of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to implement all the interfaces to have a simple working `Date` class.

I would suggest that you forget about Java's `Date` class and consider what you think is needed for a date class. For example:

- Get/set day of month
- Get/set month
- Get/set year
- Get day of week
- `toString()`

Would give you a pretty good basic date class.
For the sake of completeness, I'll tell you what the interfaces are for. You can decide whether to implement them based on how much you have learned and the assignment's requirements:

- `Serializable` is for saving your object to a stream. You actually don't need to do much work to implement it.
- `Comparable` is for comparing objects (`date1.compareTo(date2)` should return an integer indicating whether `date1` is before, after, or the same as `date2`).
- `Clonable` is for creating a deep copy of the object.

Comment: could you tell me how it will defer with the original date class

Comment: Well first of all the original `Date` class is storing a date and a time (the suggested functions I put above are just for the date part). Secondly, all the methods you see deprecated in the `Date` class are deprecated because that functionality is performed by a different class (`Calendar`). It depends on what functionality you need. If you don't know you should ask the professor.

Answer (score 7):

1. [Serializable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) means the class can be Serialized to a transportable binary form.
2. [Clonable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) means the class can be cloned, this is very tricky to get right, mainly because of inheritance and mutability concerns.
3. [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) means the class supports being *compared* to other classes of the same type.

Of these `Comparable` is the only one that requires any code to function, it is also probably the only one that is any use in your scenario.

`Serializable` is what is called a `Marker Interface` it doesn't require any code to cause anything to happen since it doesn't have any methods to implement. It just exists to *mark* the object as supporting something and another class and check for this interface and do things based on its existence.

`Cloneable` is something you want to stay away from if at all possible. Cloning objects in Java is not straight forward, has lots of gotchas and generally behaves in the most non-intuitive ways imaginable. If you really want to know about this, learn about this, [read this article](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=71).

`Comparable` is very valuable, it lets you compare to like objects to see if one is less than, equal or greater than another. This is a requirement for *sorting* and Collections classes that support [Comparators](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). `Comparators` can be thought of as stand alone implementations of `Comparable` that can be plugged into other classes to control how objects are compared.

`java.util.Date` is a tricky class, it appears to be a straight forward struct type class with some mutators and convenience methods, but the underlying problem domain for calendar data isn't that simple. Calendar math has lots of *exceptional* cases. That is why there are so many methods on `java.util.Date` that are deprecated, they produced **wrong** behavior in many cases.

For some more code to study, look at this [temporal package](https://github.com/fuzzylollipop/sqlck/tree/master/src/main/java/com/vertigrated/temporal) I developed to wrap the standard Java `Calendar` with very basic [Date](https://github.com/fuzzylollipop/sqlck/blob/master/src/main/java/com/vertigrated/temporal/Date.java), [Time](https://github.com/fuzzylollipop/sqlck/blob/master/src/main/java/com/vertigrated/temporal/Time.java) and [TimeStamp](https://github.com/fuzzylollipop/sqlck/blob/master/src/main/java/com/vertigrated/temporal/TimeStamp.java) classes, they all just delegate to an instance of `Calendar` for the actual calcuations.

**NOTE:** *this library code pre-dates JodaTime for those of you that might complain about just not using that library.*

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a lab project, why don't you list down what kind of function a 'simple' Date class needs and should have. For example, toString() -- returns a string representation of a Data or toMilliSecond() -- returns the number of milliSecond from the reference time.